# How to Rename Layer With Auto Identify Horizontal and Verticle Frame [Photoshop Scripting]

Tags: javascript, typescript, photoshop, photoshop-script, windows-scripting

i am new to photoshop scripting.
i want to load a PSD File which have 2 Verticle Photos and 3 Horizontal Photos,I select that Layer.
Now i want that All selected layer has been renamed to Verticle with **VFrame** and Horizontal With **HFrame** And PSD Saved With That Name **2v3h_My Name_0001**
How can this be done? Can somebody please share the javascript For Photoshop?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some code to your question, so we can better understand your question and possibly identify the issue(s). Read how to create a [mcve] before adding your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is your first question, welcome to StackOverflow. There are lots of Photoshop Scripting guides out there. [This one](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/introduction-to-photoshop-scripting/) cover the basics.

The script you want needs to:

- Loop over the layers (we'll leave out groups, that gets
  complicated fast)
- Identify if a layer is horizontal or vertical
- Rename the layer appropriately
- Duplicate the document with the new
  name according to the number of horizontal layers

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF 

// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;
var numOfLayers = srcDoc.layers.length;
var vCount = 0;
var hCount = 0;


// main loop
for (var i = numOfLayers -1; i >= 0  ; i--) 
{
  // get a referenec to each layer as we loop over them
  var thisLayer = srcDoc.layers[i];

  // get the layer bounds of each layer as you go
  srcDoc.activeLayer = thisLayer;
  var lb = get_layer_bounds();

  // set a variable to for portrait or landscape
  var portrait = true;

  // if layer is wider than it is long,
  // it's landscape
  if (lb[0] > lb[1]) portrait = false;
  //alert(lb[0] + "," + lb[1] + "\n" + portrait + "\n" +thisLayer.name);

  // ignore the background layer
  // if there is one
  if (thisLayer.isBackgroundLayer == false)
  {
    if (portrait)
      {
        srcDoc.artLayers[i].name = "HFrame";
        // add one to the horizontal count
        hCount +=1
      }
    else
      {
        srcDoc.artLayers[i].name = "VFrame";
        // add one to the vertical count
        vCount+=1
      }
  }
}
var docName = srcDoc.name.substring(0, srcDoc.name.length -4);
var imgName = vCount + "v" + hCount + "h_" + docName + "_0001.psd";
duplicateIt(imgName);


// Set Display Dialogs back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL



// function GET LAYER BOUNDS ()
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
function get_layer_bounds()
{
  var x = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds[0]);
  var y = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds[1]);
  var x1 = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds[2]);
  var y1 = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.activeLayer.bounds[3]);

  var selW = parseFloat(x1-x);
  var selH = parseFloat(y1-y);

  // return the results as an array
  return [selW, selH];
}


function duplicateIt(str)
{
  // duplicate image into new document
  if (arguments.length == 0) str = "temp";

  var id428 = charIDToTypeID( "Dplc" );
  var desc92 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id429 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref27 = new ActionReference();
  var id430 = charIDToTypeID( "Dcmn" );
  var id431 = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var id432 = charIDToTypeID( "Frst" );
  ref27.putEnumerated( id430, id431, id432 );
  desc92.putReference( id429, ref27 );
  var id433 = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
  desc92.putString( id433, str ); // name
  executeAction( id428, desc92, DialogModes.NO );
}
```

Comment: i Want rename only selected frame. Not All Frame.

Comment: I want to add also save option in desktop and close it.